# Largest values of spin-orbit coupling

Tags: topological-insulators

Which are some of the materials with the largest ratio spin-orbit coupling constant/hopping constant? I'm trying to compute energy bands for different values of $t$ (hopping constant) and $\lambda_{SO}$ (spin-orbit coupling) using Kane-Mele's model, but I'm not sure what are some sensible values for real materials with strong-orbit interaction. In addition, is there in principle a maximum ratio $\lambda_{SO}/t$ attainable in a real material?

Comment: Update: I found this nice paper that answers to a good extent my question http://journals.jps.jp/doi/pdf/10.7566/JPSJ.84.121003

Comment: You can answer your own question, it's not a problem :-)